# Where do I look to solve a ChunkLoadingError: Loading chunk nameofchunk failed in a Vue application?

Tags: vue.js, code-splitting

My application is working fine on my development machine, but once I run
`npm run production` (it compiles successfully) and upload the chunks onto the production server, I get an error of the form:

`[vue-router] Failed to resolve async component default: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk nameOfChunk failed. (missing: https://nameofdomain/nameOfChunk.js)`

`[vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:`

I've tried emptying browser caches (as suggested in other answers) to no avail.

Chrome is reporting that Vue is running in development mode.  If this is a clue, where do I turn on production mode? I thought I'd dealt with that with  `npm run production`

Where do I look/what do I do next to resolve this problem?

Thanks, Tom

Comment: Are any other assets uploaded onto the production server accessible?

Comment: @Richter - yes, the site "looks" functional with images and style sheets loaded as expected. It's just when any navigation item is clicked that the veneer disappears.

Comment: Is the production script custom or something like this: `"production": "vue-cli-service serve --mode production"`

Comment: It's this: `"production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",`

Comment: Can you see if this github issue is related? https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/2064

Comment: I believe I've seen something like this before and the issue was due to the use of `"@"` as an alias for "src" in describing the path to the component location. You can try setting switching to an absolute path to see if that addresses it, if this applies.